# How to send more data through Ajax to the Codeigniter calendar

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, calendar

I am using a calendar example for php Codeigniter.

I have a table called meetings that has an `id, datemeeting , data, and projectuid`.

Before selecting in the calendar and writing to the calendar, to first choose a `projectuid` from the combobox and send it to the POST in the `projectuid`.

I have no ideia how to do this in jQuery

```
<div id="content">
    <style type="text/css">
        .calendar {
            font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;
        }
        table.calendar {
            margin: auto; border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .calendar .days td {
            width: 80px; height: 80px; padding: 4px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            vertical-align: top;
            background-color: #DEF;
        }
        .calendar .days td:hover {
            background-color: #FFF;
        }
        .calendar .highlight {
            font-weight: bold; color: #00F;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <?php
        echo form_label('Project', 'projectUID');
        echo br(1);
        echo form_dropdown('projectUID', $projects, set_value('projectUID', $projects));
    ?>

    <center><?php echo $calendar; ?></center>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.calendar .day').click(function() {
            day_num = $(this).find('.day_num').html();
            day_data = prompt('Enter Meeting', $(this).find('.content').html());
            if (day_data != null)) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: window.location,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        day: day_num,
                        data: day_data

                    },
                    success: function(msg) {
                        location.reload();
                    }                       
                });

            }

        });

    });

    </script>

</div>
```

Comment: My name isn't Pedro. Also, could you try to explain a little more clearly what you have tried and what isn't working for you? Are you getting errors? Does any of it work at all? We can't just build the thing for you (well, we won't)...

Comment: the calendar its working only with date and data , we need to pass the projectuid also  echo form_dropdown('projectUID' , i am working on this when i have finish i will reply the result

Comment: its working now

the key elements were adding $js

echo form_dropdown('projectUID', $projects, set_value('projectUID', $projects),$js);

and adding var select_x=document.getElementById("shirts").value;